How can I configure JerseyTest with Spock in Spring Boot Application for Unit Tests?
I want to test the next controller class using Jersey Test in my Spring Boot application.
Controller Class
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/demo")
public class UserController {

    private final IUserService service;

    public UserController(IUserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/register", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> registerUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserRequest userRequest) {
        UserResponse user = service.createUser(userRequest);
        return ResponseEntity.status(CREATED).body(user);
    }
}


UserRequest Class
public class UserRequest {

    @NotBlank
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank
    private String lastName;
    @NotBlank
    private String email;
    @NotBlank
    private String password;
    @NotBlank
    private String afm;
    @NotBlank
    private String birthDate;
    @NotBlank
    private String mobileNumber;
    @NotBlank
    private String cardNumber;

//getters and setters, no arg and full arg constructor


build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}

group = 'com'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    compileOnly 'jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-api:11.0.0-M4'

    testImplementation 'org.eclipse:yasson'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework:jersey-test-framework-core:4.0.0-M1'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers:jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2:4.0.0-M1'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-http:4.0.0-M1'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:4.0.0-M1'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:4.0.0-M1'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:4.0.0-M1'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:4.0.0-M1'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.5'
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.1'
    testImplementation 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy'
    testImplementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.17'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.4-M4-groovy-4.0'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.4-M4-groovy-4.0'
    testImplementation 'jakarta.json.bind:jakarta.json.bind-api'
    testImplementation 'org.eclipse:yasson'
    testImplementation 'io.github.joke:spock-mockable:2.3.2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:mysql'
    testImplementation 'com.github.dasniko:testcontainers-keycloak:3.4.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

task createTestResources() {
    copy {
        from 'env'
        include 'test.properties'
        into 'src/test/resources'
        expand project.properties
    }
}

clean.doFirst {
    delete 'src/test/resources/test.properties'
}


Below you can see the test along with the configuration
Test class
class UserControllerSpec extends ResourceSpecification {

    static final String REGISTER_URL = '/api/v1/demo/register'

    @Subject
    UserController controller

    IUserService service

    @Override
    protected createResource() {
        service = Mock()
        controller = new UserController(service)
    }

    def 'Successfully calling the preview endpoint'() {
        given: 'a valid request'
        def request = TestFixtures.createUserRequest()

        and: 'an expected response'
        def expectedResponse = TestFixtures.createUserResponse()

        when: 'the controller is called'
        def response = jerseyTest.target(REGISTER_URL).request().post(Entity.json(request))

        then: 'response should have status 201'
        response.getStatus() == 201

        and: 'the cancel preview service is called once with the correct request parameters'
        1 * service.createUser({
            it.firstName == request.firstName &&
                    it.lastName == request.lastName &&
                    it.email == request.email &&
                    it.password == request.password &&
                    it.afm == request.afm &&
                    it.birthDate == request.birthDate &&
                    it.mobileNumber == request.mobileNumber &&
                    it.cardNumber == request.cardNumber
        }) >> expectedResponse

        and: 'the actual response should contain the expected values'
        def actualResponse = response.readEntity(UserResponse.class)
        actualResponse == expectedResponse
    }
}

Configuration Class
abstract class ResourceSpecification extends Specification {

    JerseyTest jerseyTest
    JsonSlurper jsonSlurper

    protected abstract createResource()

    def setup() {
        jerseyTest = new JerseyTest() {
            @Override
            protected Application configure() {
                new ResourceConfig()
                        .register(createResource())
            }
        }
        jerseyTest.setUp()
        jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    }

    def cleanup() {
        jerseyTest.tearDown()
    }
}

My test fails with the next error:
Jul 29, 2024 8:37:50 PM org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer <init>
INFO: Creating GrizzlyTestContainer configured at the base URI http://localhost:9998/
Jul 29, 2024 8:37:50 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider com.ebanking.system.controller.UserController registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider com.ebanking.system.controller.UserController will be ignored. 
20:37:51.233 [Test worker] INFO org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version -- HV000001: Hibernate Validator 8.0.1.Final
Jul 29, 2024 8:37:51 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:9998]
Jul 29, 2024 8:37:51 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
Jul 29, 2024 8:37:51 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [localhost:9998]

Too few invocations for:

1 * service.createUser({
            it.firstName == request.firstName &&
                    it.lastName == request.lastName &&
                    it.email == request.email &&
                    it.password == request.password &&
                    it.afm == request.afm &&
                    it.birthDate == request.birthDate &&
                    it.mobileNumber == request.mobileNumber &&
                    it.cardNumber == request.cardNumber
        }) >> expectedResponse   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None


Too few invocations for:

1 * service.createUser({
            it.firstName == request.firstName &&
                    it.lastName == request.lastName &&
                    it.email == request.email &&
                    it.password == request.password &&
                    it.afm == request.afm &&
                    it.birthDate == request.birthDate &&
                    it.mobileNumber == request.mobileNumber &&
                    it.cardNumber == request.cardNumber
        }) >> expectedResponse   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None


    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionScope.verifyInteractions(InteractionScope.java:110)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.leaveScope(MockController.java:95)
    at com.ebanking.system.controller.UserControllerSpec.Successfully calling the preview endpoint(UserControllerSpec.groovy:33)

The ResourceSpecification class works well with OpenLiberty applications but it seems to me that it does not happen the same with Spring Boot ones. What am I missing? Any suggestions?

Does the exception include an unmatched interaction? Please include all the relevant versions.

Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Thank you. Otherwise, users can only speculate or at best make educated guesses. You will get much better answers, if they can reproduce your problem. E.g., nobody can see the field data types in your UserRequest class and check each data type for correct implementation of equals().

Thank you for feedback. I made some updates to the question although I think there's still room for improvement. However, do these help in giving a better context?

The jersey versions are still missing, same as the spring boot version.

Provided the whole build.gradle file

Thank you for your contributions. I thought that it is better to proceed with MockMvc for my issue.
